# When linking static libraries (*.a) inside an Ios project i have warning: unknown dwarf DW_FORM_strp

Tags: ios, delphi

Under delphi tokyo, when I link a static libraries (*.a) inside an Ios project like this :

```
procedure StubProc1; cdecl; external 'FBSDKCoreKit.a' name 'OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken';
```

I receive a lot of warnings like this one:

> ld: warning: unknown dwarf DW_FORM_strp (offset=0xFFFF6E38) is too
>   big in
>   C:\Dev\lib\ios\facebook\FBSDKShareKit.framework\FBSDKShareKit.a(FBSDKAppInviteContent.o)

Any idea what goes wrong?  What exactly does `unknown dwarf DW_FORM_strp` mean?

Comment: I don't know anything about iOS programing in Delphi but was curious about this lost fantasy figure. Some Googling for *"unknown dwarf" ios* brought me to [this page](https://delphiworlds.com/2013/11/checking-for-an-internet-connection-on-mobile-devices-with-delphi-xe5/) where it basically said 'recreate your project file'.

Comment: thanks Jan, i try to recreate my project, didn't help :( however the project work fine, i just have theses warning at compile time and was curious to know why ...

Comment: I bet it will not give you the same warnings when building the application on release mode.

Comment: yes the same in release :(

Comment: I found this blog : https://www.developpeur-pascal.fr/p/___001-contourner-l-erreur-ld-warning-unknown-dwarf-dw_form_strp-offset0xffffff99-is-too-big-in-xxxarawo.html Not sure it helps or not.

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu a little but not really, he just say he don't have this in release when me in opposite i have it in release :(

Comment: Do not try to develop iOS apps with Delphi. It wastes your time.

Comment: @shawn: absolutely not, i have made with delphi some app on ios that are incredibly fast, and better than equivalent made with xcode

Comment: Well, I used Delphi for long time, and familiar Swift, too. In my opinion (just my opinion), I found I spent too much time to debug strange problems in Delphi for iOS. If I use Swift instead, the development progress is very smooth (and still fast with Swift). And, I have investigated the problem you met, hope my finding helps.  :D

Comment: any more questions?

Answer (score 0):

Reference code:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/cxxfilt/cxxfilt-9/cxxfilt/binutils/dwarf.c.auto.html

```
/* Process the contents of a .debug_info section.  If do_loc is non-zero
   then we are scanning for location lists and we do not want to display
   anything to the user.  */

static int
process_debug_info (struct dwarf_section *section, void *file,
int do_loc)
```

Then it calls `read_and_display_attr` -> `read_and_display_attr_value` -> `fetch_indirect_string`:

```
offset -= section->address;
if (offset > section->size)
    {
        warn (_("DW_FORM_strp offset too big: %lx\n"), offset);
        return _("<offset is too big>");
}
```

So, it seems that this warning is only for debug purpose only.

Maybe your third party library lacks debug info, or something incompatible for debug (remember, even if you are building for release, there can still be some debug info in your app).

As it is for debug only, once you have successfully compiled your project, this warning shouldn't matter.